# How to set/modify value of a collection field from MongoDB Atlas triggers?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a MongoDB in Atlas and a collection that has createdAt/lastModifiedAt fields. I would like to set up triggers to automatically handle these fields. The following is my trigger for setting createdAt:

```
const collection = context.services.get("comand-dev").db("test").collection("ownerDetails");
const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;
collection;
collection.update(
  {_id : docId} ,
  { 
    $set : 
     {
       createdAt: Date()
     } 
  }
);
```

This trigger function throws the following error and I don't know what I need to do to have a successfull trigger:

```
TypeError: 'update' is not a function
> trace: 
TypeError: 'update' is not a function
    at exports (function.js:44:3)
    at apply (<native code>)
    at function_wrapper.js:2:3
    at <anonymous>:12:1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/update-documents-in-mongodb/#update-a-single-document) you should be using `updateOne` or `updateMany`.